# Android studio adding external source directory

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

Android studio doesnt add my external jni source folder into the project with the below configuration. What could be wrong?

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.android.gl2jni"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 5
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        }


            sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs += ['/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/username/Projects/UserInterface/geo/Geo']

    }
```

it says Error:Could not find property 'main' on SourceSet container.

Comment: NDK does not support paths with spaces; but you can use relative path, if it does not have spaces.

Comment: You can also try `sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs += ['~/Projects/UserInterface/geo/Geo']`, or if nothing else helps, create a symbolic link with no spaces to the Projects directory (may require sudo).

Answer (score 1):

Your path contains spaces, test using a path like:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh_HD_2/username/Projects/UserInterface/geo/Geo
```